# error FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-111

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
        while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
            }
        } finally {


            if (!canvas.equals(null)) { // error is here.
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should post some explanation and a question instead of simply pasting code with an error message

Comment: This is what i get in the LogCat.
01-25 14:25:54.628: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-197
01-25 14:25:54.628: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 14:25:54.628: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):  at com.zm.atz.Maingame_m1.render(Maingame_m1.java:64)
01-25 14:25:54.628: E/AndroidRuntime(3357):  at com.zm.atz.Mainthread_m1.run(Mainthread_m1.java:31)

Comment: You get more than that. Anyway, you want ` if(canvas != null)` because right now you might be calling a method on a null object. And please don't post your logcat in comments...it's so hard to read. Instead, use the edit button below the tags in your question to add it to your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709799/how-to-solve-fatal-exception-thread-11)

Answer (score 1):

If there is any error executing

```
canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
```

then `canvas` will be `null`. This is what I suspect what's going on here.

Change

```
if (!canvas.equals(null)) {
```

to

```
if (canvas != null) {
```